# QPushButton, создать обработчики в цикле

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, qtablewidget, qpushbutton

Есть примерно такой код:

```
i=0
for x in range(5):
    self.tableWidget.setCellWidget(i,1, QPushButton("Изменить..."))
    i+=1
```

В цикле в столбце создаю кнопки.
Как для них создать разные обработчики `self.Button.clicked.connect()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант, это может  выглядеть так:

```
from PyQt5 import Qt
import sys

class MainWindow(Qt.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        Qt.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.tableWidget = Qt.QTableWidget()
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(5)
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(5)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.tableWidget)

        for x in range(5):
            self.button = Qt.QPushButton('Изменить... {}'.format(x), self)
            self.tableWidget.setCellWidget(x, 1, self.button)
            self.button.clicked.connect(lambda state, numButton=x: self.button_pushed(numButton))

    def button_pushed(self, numButton):    
        print ('Pushed button `{}`'.format(numButton))


app = Qt.QApplication(sys.argv)
w   = MainWindow()
w.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо, завтра попробую...

Comment: Отлично! Спасибо. А как сделать тоже самое для обычной ячейки self.tableWidget.setItem(x,0, QTableWidgetItem('Ячейка'))?

Answer (score 1):

```
for x in range(5):
      pb = Qt.QPushButton("Изменить...")
      pb.clicked.connect(getattr(self, "clicked_{}".format(x)))
      self.tableWidget.setCellWidget(x, 1, pb)

def clicked_1(self):
      todo

def clicked_2(self):
      todo
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, завтра попробую...

Comment: Интересно, но выдает ошибку KeyError: 'clicked_1' в строке pb.clicked.connect(globals()["clicked_{}".format(x)]) - похоже словарь globals не имеет такого ключа. Уверены, что ваш код работоспособен?

Comment: @MyNick Да, забыл, что это класс. Через `getattr` все работает: выше в коде поменял.